# If Else VBA Issue

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is that my code does not pick up the "Medium" variable

```
If Range("B24").Value = "Medium" Then
Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
```

Can you please advise what's wrong with it ("Standard" should uncover rows, "Medium" should keep them hidden but unhide the Sheet2, High again keeps the rows hidden but unhides Sheet2, if (B24) is empty it should keep rows and Sheet2 hidden:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("B24").Value = "Standard" Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
End If
    If Range("B24").Value = "Medium" Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
End If
    If Range("B24").Value = "High" Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
End If
    Else
    Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
End If
    If Range("B24").Value = "Standard" Then
    Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are obviously missing an `If`, and your code should not be working. This is how it looks like, when it is formatted:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("B24").Value = "Standard" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
    End If

    If Range("B24").Value = "Medium" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
    End If

    If Range("B24").Value = "High" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
    End If
'Is this Else an IF?
Else
    Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
End If

If Range("B24").Value = "Standard" Then
    Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

If you omit the If-Else, the code would look a bit better with a Select-Case statement:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case Range("B24")

    Case "Standard"
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
        Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Case "Medium"
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
        Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Case "High"
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
        Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Case Else
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
        Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End Select

End Sub
```

You can probably go one step further, by writing `Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True` before the select case and remove this line from cases, thus following the Do-Not-Repeat-Yourself principle. But in this case it is probably not needed.

If you want to add a second range, something like this is possible:

```
Select Case True    
    Case Range("B24") = "Standard"      
    Case Range("B26") = "Medium"        
End Select
```

However, it would evaluate just once, thus if both are true, `B26` is not going to happen.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for that. It works perfectly. PS. @Vityata Can you please advise what are the best books/resources to develop knowledge of VBA (Microsoft website?)?

Comment: @WestRay - welcome :) Probably about books - John Walkenbach and Tom Urtis (see them in Amazon.com), about site - cpearson.com.

Comment: Greatly obliged for that! I will take a look right away. Thank you :)

Comment: Quick question: if I wanted to add another Select Case Range("B26") with similar criterias (to what's in your code), how would I do it?

Comment: @WestRay - see the edit, but it really depends on what you are doing exactly.

Comment: Hi @Vityata can you please see my latest post. It relates to the Select Case True code.